# UITextField sentence capitalize issue with becomeFirstResponder in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitextfield, capitalize

I'm having two UITextFields in my UIViewController. First UITextField is for having numbers and second UITextField is for having text. I'm concerning here about the second UITextField which is having text. I have enabled ***Capitalization = Sentences*** for the second UITextField in the storyboard also.

When I completed entering number value to first UITextField (Did End On Exit) I call a method and it has following logic

```
[sender resignFirstResponder];

if (_descriptionTextField.text.length == 0) {
        [_descriptionTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

As I expected the second UITextField is ready to get user input but the first letter of the sentence is not capitalise. After a period (.) it will capitalise and also if I tap on the second UITextField first, to enter text, then also the capitalise thing is working.

But I need to capitalise the sentence after I enter value to first UITextField and tap on the Next button in the keyboard which will ready the second UITextField to enter value. Where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
if (_descriptionTextField.text.length == 0)

 {

_descriptionTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;

        [_descriptionTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }
```